# CSS add line break between two elements

Tags: html, css

I have this `html` output:

```
  return '<div class="band"><i class="'.USER.'" aria-hidden="true"></i> '.(isset($_SESSION['logedAs'])? $_SESSION['logedAs'] : null).' <i class="'.$icon.' ribbon" aria-hidden="true"></i> '.$ribbon.'</div>';
```

and i need to add brake before `icon` with class 'ribbon'.
I tried with this in `CSS` but it won't work:

```
.ribbon span::before { 
        content: "\A";
        white-space: pre;;
}
```

Comment: I tried this already and nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can insert a block content before the icon to break it down:

```css
.ribbon:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="band">
  <i class="" aria-hidden="true">icon1</i> Some text
  <i class=" ribbon" aria-hidden="true">icon2</i> $ribbon
</div>
```

Comment: It works in this way if is single class in my case i have double class

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, but if your have multiple class just append them: `.class-1.class-2.etc.ribbon:before { ... }`

Comment: M class looks like this: `class="test1 ribbon"` (two words as a name)

Comment: I'm pretty confused  now. Are you sure you have copy/pasted my solution in and it didn't work?

Comment: Your solution is work with one class name but won't work with multiple classes (few names in same class)